# How to input data into a database from two different tables with different forms

Tags: php, mysql

Hi im doing my final project this year. I need to input data into a database together with month and day. However, month and day is recalled from another database. Some of codes does not work. Btw im using php and mysql.

there are 3 pages.

This is the first page: pilih.php

```
<html>

<form action="pilih_process.php" method="POST">

<table>

<tr>
    <td>Month:</td>
    <td><select name="month"/>
            <option value="January">January</option>
            <option value="February">February</option>
            <option value="March">March</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Day:</td>
    <td><select name="day"/>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Group:</td>
    <td><select name="group"/>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/></td>
</tr>


</table>

</form>

</html>
```

This is the second page: pilih_process.php

```
<html>

<?php

include ('connect_database.php')

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT Student_ID, Student_Name FROM student_details WHERE    Group_ID=$group");

$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$group = $_POST['group'];    

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Month: $month</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Day: $day</td>";
echo "</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Group: $group</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

echo "<form action='pilih_process2.php' method='POST'>";

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>ID</th>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "</tr>";


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1) )
{
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row['Student_ID'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['Student_Name']. '</td>';

echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='status[]' value='Expert'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='status[]' value='Intermediate'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='status[]' value='Amature'/></td>";
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='status[]' value='Noob'/></td>";

echo "</tr>";
}

echo "<tr>";

echo "<td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/></td>";

echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";

echo "</form>";

?>

</html>
```

This is the third page: pilih_process2.php

```
<html>

<?php

include ('connect_database.php');

$month = $_SESSION['month'];                //From First page: pilih.php
$day = $_SESSION["day"];                    //From First page: pilih.php
$student_id = $_SESSION["Student_ID"];      //From Second page: pilih_process.php
$student_name = $_SESSION["Student_Name"];  //From Second page: pilih_process.php
$group = $_POST['group'];                   //From First page: pilih.php
$status = $_POST['status'];                 //From Second page: pilih_process.php

mysql_query("INSERT into mencuba(Month_ID, Day_ID, Student_ID, Student_Name, Group_ID, Status) VALUES('$month', '$day', '$student_id', '$student_name', '$group', '$status')");


/*
$status_test = $_GET['status'];   //I DONT KNOW WHETHER THIS ARRAY METHOD IS CORRECT
for($i=0; $i < count($checked); $i++){
echo "Selected " . $checked[$i] . "<br/>";
}
*/

?>
```

Here how it goes:

1. From the First page, the user have to choose which month, day and group and submit.
2. On the Second page, it displays the Student ID, Student Name, Group and Status which is based on what group.
3. For the status, the user has to pick one and submit.
4. On the third page. The data Month_ID, Day_ID, Student_ID, Student_Name, Group_ID and Status will be inserted into the database.

PROBLEMS:

1. When I insert the data, only Month_ID, Day_ID, Group_ID and Status is inserted into the database. I was unable to call the variable Student_ID and variable Student_Name.
2. it only insert one data. if there are 100 data to enter obviously ihave to use array which i do not really sure how to use.
3. We are taught simple PHP and MySql

Comment: Ok. The first thing I'm going to ask you to do is to learn about [PDO](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php). The mysql_* functions are considered deprecated, and can/will be removed in future versions of PHP.

Comment: The second thing to note: where do you set Student_ID and Student_Name into the session? In the provided code, you don't;  they'd then have no reason to be contained in the session. For that matter, where do you start the session with `session_start()`? Session variables are unavailable until that call is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in other answers, there are a few things going on here.

1. You are trying to use the variable $group before you've set it
2. You are using raw POST data in a query - this is very very bad practice - even if it's a project you'll score better for doing it better. At the very least wrap that in `mysql_real_escape_string` so it looks like you tried.

`$group = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['group']);`

**As for the main issue:**

You need to pass the first forms parameter to the second form. Just putting them in the table will not save them. Pass them as hidden form values

`echo "<input type="hidden" name="group" value="'.$group.'" />";`

Beyond that, if you expect to have multiple results for your query (ie: multiple people from one group) then you need to change your logic again because each one will just be overriding the form values from the one before.

Comment: That's one of the main issues as well (and the insertion in the last file also needs the variables to have escaped strings)

Comment: Thanks. This method works. I want it hidden like that :)

Answer (score 1):

You place `$group` in your query before you initiate it. you must initiate it first and then place it to query.

**like this :**

```
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$group = $_POST['group'];

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT 
          Student_ID, Student_Name 
          FROM student_details 
          WHERE Group_ID=$group");
```

**About `status` thing**

you have to use `select` instead of `checkbox` , if you want to give multiple select use another `name` property for each field in your form.

Comment: This _is_ true (and helpful), but there are many other problems. Can you find other issues in the code?